# Evaluate Time Between Elements of Row

Tags: r, time, dplyr, data-manipulation, lubridate

I'm trying to evaluate time elements of a row to create a TRUE/FALSE column. For instance:

```
datetime
10/10/15 0:45
10/1/15 0:45
10/10/15 0:30
10/1/15 0:30
10/10/15 0:15
10/1/15 0:15
10/10/15 0:00
10/1/15 0:00
10/10/15 10:45
10/10/15 1:45
10/10/15 10:30
10/10/15 1:30
10/10/15 10:15
10/10/15 1:15
10/10/15 11:45
10/10/15 11:30
10/10/15 11:15
10/10/15 11:00
10/10/15 12:45
10/10/15 12:30
10/10/15 12:15
10/10/15 12:00
10/10/15 13:45
10/10/15 13:30
10/10/15 13:15
10/10/15 14:45
10/10/15 14:30
10/10/15 14:15
10/10/15 14:00
10/10/15 15:45
10/10/15 15:30
10/10/15 15:15
10/10/15 15:00
10/10/15 16:45
10/10/15 16:30
10/10/15 16:15
10/10/15 17:45
10/10/15 17:30
10/10/15 17:15
10/10/15 17:00
10/10/15 18:45
10/10/15 18:30
10/10/15 18:15
10/10/15 18:00
10/10/15 19:45
10/10/15 19:30
10/10/15 19:15
10/10/15 20:45
10/10/15 2:45
10/10/15 20:30
10/10/15 2:30
10/10/15 20:15
10/10/15 2:15
10/10/15 20:00
10/10/15 2:00
10/10/15 21:45
10/10/15 21:30
10/10/15 21:15
10/10/15 21:00
10/10/15 22:45
10/10/15 22:30
10/10/15 22:15
10/10/15 23:45
10/10/15 23:30
10/10/15 23:15
10/10/15 23:00
10/10/15 3:45
10/10/15 3:30
10/10/15 3:15
10/10/15 3:00
10/10/15 4:45
10/10/15 4:30
10/10/15 4:15
10/10/15 5:45
10/10/15 5:30
10/10/15 5:15
10/10/15 5:00
10/10/15 6:45
10/10/15 6:30
10/10/15 6:15
10/10/15 6:00
10/10/15 7:45
10/10/15 7:30
10/10/15 7:15
10/10/15 8:45
10/10/15 8:30
10/10/15 8:15
10/10/15 8:00
10/10/15 9:45
10/10/15 9:30
10/10/15 9:15
10/10/15 9:00
10/1/15 10:45
10/1/15 1:45
10/1/15 10:30
10/1/15 1:30
10/1/15 10:15
10/1/15 1:15
10/1/15 10:00
10/11/15 10:45
```

Suppose I want a variable such that:

```
v1 = TRUE if 7:45<time(datetime)<8:15  
AND v1 = TRUE if 23:45<time(datetime)<0:15 (next day) 
ELSE = FALSE
```

Essentially, I'm looking for something similar to what `dplyr::mutate(between, a, b)` does, but that understands time.

My data is stored as follows:

```
$ datetime              : POSIXct, format: "2015-10-10 00:45:00" "2015-10-01 00:45:00" "2015-10-10 00:30:00" "2015-10-01 00:30:00" ...
$ year                  : int  2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 ...
$ month                 : int  10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
$ day                   : int  10 1 10 1 10 1 10 1 10 10 ...
$ minute                : int  45 45 30 30 14 14 0 0 44 44 ...
```

Comment: I should say that, I know how to get there from first principle with lots of intermediate steps.  I am looking for a more elegant, compact solution.

Comment: Please give a reproducible example or use `dput`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is in a csv called `test.csv`

```
library(data.table)
library(fasttime)
data = fread('test.csv',header = TRUE,sep='\n')
data[,datetime:=fastPOSIXct(datetime)]
data[,v1:=FALSE][as.ITime(datetime) %between% as.ITime(c('01:45','08:45')) | as.ITime(datetime) %between% as.ITime(c('23:45','23:59')), v1:=TRUE]
```

You need to adjust the times as you want

```
               datetime    v1
 1: 2010-10-15 01:45:00  TRUE
 2: 2010-01-15 00:45:00 FALSE
 3: 2010-10-15 01:30:00 FALSE
 4: 2010-01-15 00:30:00 FALSE
...
```

Comment: This almost works. Im trying to understand the syntax so I can figure out why it works on the CSV but not the data frame.

Comment: because I use data.table, do data = as.data.table(your data.frame)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare times and not respective of the date, you can convert the date-times all to one date (i.e., today's date) using `strftime` followed by `as.POSIXct` and then compare times. Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
result <- df %>% mutate(hm = as.POSIXct(strftime(datetime, format="%H:%M"),format="%H:%M"),
                        v1 = ifelse((as.POSIXct("7:45", format="%H:%M") < hm & hm < as.POSIXct("8:15", format="%H:%M")) |
                                    (as.POSIXct("23:45", format="%H:%M") < hm & hm < as.POSIXct("0:15", format="%H:%M")),
                                    TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
                 select(-hm)
```

First create a column `hm` that is the times from `datetime` but with the date set to today. Then use `ifelse` with your condition to compare times in a range. With your supplied data (only the `datetime` column as a data frame `df`):

```
print(result)
##               datetime    v1
##1   2015-10-10 00:45:00 FALSE
##2   2015-10-01 00:45:00 FALSE
##3   2015-10-10 00:30:00 FALSE
##4   2015-10-01 00:30:00 FALSE
##5   2015-10-10 00:15:00 FALSE
##6   2015-10-01 00:15:00 FALSE
##7   2015-10-10 00:00:00 FALSE
##8   2015-10-01 00:00:00 FALSE
##9   2015-10-10 10:45:00 FALSE
##10  2015-10-10 01:45:00 FALSE
##11  2015-10-10 10:30:00 FALSE
##12  2015-10-10 01:30:00 FALSE
##13  2015-10-10 10:15:00 FALSE
##14  2015-10-10 01:15:00 FALSE
##15  2015-10-10 11:45:00 FALSE
##16  2015-10-10 11:30:00 FALSE
##17  2015-10-10 11:15:00 FALSE
##18  2015-10-10 11:00:00 FALSE
##19  2015-10-10 12:45:00 FALSE
##20  2015-10-10 12:30:00 FALSE
##21  2015-10-10 12:15:00 FALSE
##22  2015-10-10 12:00:00 FALSE
##23  2015-10-10 13:45:00 FALSE
##24  2015-10-10 13:30:00 FALSE
##25  2015-10-10 13:15:00 FALSE
##26  2015-10-10 14:45:00 FALSE
##27  2015-10-10 14:30:00 FALSE
##28  2015-10-10 14:15:00 FALSE
##29  2015-10-10 14:00:00 FALSE
##30  2015-10-10 15:45:00 FALSE
##31  2015-10-10 15:30:00 FALSE
##32  2015-10-10 15:15:00 FALSE
##33  2015-10-10 15:00:00 FALSE
##34  2015-10-10 16:45:00 FALSE
##35  2015-10-10 16:30:00 FALSE
##36  2015-10-10 16:15:00 FALSE
##37  2015-10-10 17:45:00 FALSE
##38  2015-10-10 17:30:00 FALSE
##39  2015-10-10 17:15:00 FALSE
##40  2015-10-10 17:00:00 FALSE
##41  2015-10-10 18:45:00 FALSE
##42  2015-10-10 18:30:00 FALSE
##43  2015-10-10 18:15:00 FALSE
##44  2015-10-10 18:00:00 FALSE
##45  2015-10-10 19:45:00 FALSE
##46  2015-10-10 19:30:00 FALSE
##47  2015-10-10 19:15:00 FALSE
##48  2015-10-10 20:45:00 FALSE
##49  2015-10-10 02:45:00 FALSE
##50  2015-10-10 20:30:00 FALSE
##51  2015-10-10 02:30:00 FALSE
##52  2015-10-10 20:15:00 FALSE
##53  2015-10-10 02:15:00 FALSE
##54  2015-10-10 20:00:00 FALSE
##55  2015-10-10 02:00:00 FALSE
##56  2015-10-10 21:45:00 FALSE
##57  2015-10-10 21:30:00 FALSE
##58  2015-10-10 21:15:00 FALSE
##59  2015-10-10 21:00:00 FALSE
##60  2015-10-10 22:45:00 FALSE
##61  2015-10-10 22:30:00 FALSE
##62  2015-10-10 22:15:00 FALSE
##63  2015-10-10 23:45:00 FALSE
##64  2015-10-10 23:30:00 FALSE
##65  2015-10-10 23:15:00 FALSE
##66  2015-10-10 23:00:00 FALSE
##67  2015-10-10 03:45:00 FALSE
##68  2015-10-10 03:30:00 FALSE
##69  2015-10-10 03:15:00 FALSE
##70  2015-10-10 03:00:00 FALSE
##71  2015-10-10 04:45:00 FALSE
##72  2015-10-10 04:30:00 FALSE
##73  2015-10-10 04:15:00 FALSE
##74  2015-10-10 05:45:00 FALSE
##75  2015-10-10 05:30:00 FALSE
##76  2015-10-10 05:15:00 FALSE
##77  2015-10-10 05:00:00 FALSE
##78  2015-10-10 06:45:00 FALSE
##79  2015-10-10 06:30:00 FALSE
##80  2015-10-10 06:15:00 FALSE
##81  2015-10-10 06:00:00 FALSE
##82  2015-10-10 07:45:00 FALSE
##83  2015-10-10 07:30:00 FALSE
##84  2015-10-10 07:15:00 FALSE
##85  2015-10-10 08:45:00 FALSE
##86  2015-10-10 08:30:00 FALSE
##87  2015-10-10 08:15:00 FALSE
##88  2015-10-10 08:00:00  TRUE
##89  2015-10-10 09:45:00 FALSE
##90  2015-10-10 09:30:00 FALSE
##91  2015-10-10 09:15:00 FALSE
##92  2015-10-10 09:00:00 FALSE
##93  2015-10-01 10:45:00 FALSE
##94  2015-10-01 01:45:00 FALSE
##95  2015-10-01 10:30:00 FALSE
##96  2015-10-01 01:30:00 FALSE
##97  2015-10-01 10:15:00 FALSE
##98  2015-10-01 01:15:00 FALSE
##99  2015-10-01 10:00:00 FALSE
##100 2015-10-11 10:45:00 FALSE
```